# Sowing cucumbers, do I really have to place the seed on its side and cover in clingfilm?

Tags: seeds, germination, cucumbers

Instructions on the packet of cucumber seeds I'm holding say I need to:

1. Plant the seed on its side
2. Cover the pot with clingfilm after sowing

I get that these are measures which will help germination. But how vital is it to get these fiddly and time-consuming details right?

Is one or the other or both of these precautions going to aid germination rates by 100%? Or 5%? Or what?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So you probably already have decently-growing cucumbers at this point but I wanted to weigh in on this.

If you planted the seeds upside down they'd mostly right themselves and grow the right way.  Robert Krulwich from NPR had a good post on this [here](http://www.npr.org/blogs/krulwich/2012/06/21/155508849/how-do-plants-know-which-way-is-up-and-which-way-is-down).

A sideways seed won't have to right itself so it will shoot up faster.

The cling film helps to do two things - hold in some heat and moisture.  Dry seeds don't sprout and spouted seeds that dry out will die.  If I start seeds inside I'll put them in a small "mini greenhouse" that is nothing more than a container with a plastic lid to help regulate the moisture level.

But with cucumbers, unless I'm making seedlings to sell/give away I'd just direct sow them once the soil's warm.  Indoor/greenhouse seedling growing would jump-start that a bit if the ground is colder in your area.

Comment: Thanks @itsmatt. If the clingfilm is so beneficial for retaining moisture around germination  Is there a reason why you especially see this instruction on cucurbit seed packets and not so much on salads and beans?

Comment: @TeaDrinker this could be just the particular writing on the packets you have.  I've not noticed this particularly on the packets I have.  I think it depends on the brand of seed you buy.  Seeds in general benefit from a warm, moist environment.